# Filtering layers by geometry type using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, filter, vector-layer, list

I need to list all layers with geometries skipping the layers without geometries.

Can I be sure `geometryType = 4` always are tables without geometries?

I cannot find the documentation explaining which number is which type in plain text.

```py
for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
   #if lyr.geometryType() != 4: #Do something
   print(lyr, lyr.geometryType())
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply use the [`isSpatial()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a2a9f0912f82c9dcd7dab3de311762e6b) method of the [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html) class, to filter geometry and *geometryless* layers.

Additionally, you should not use numbers to do such comparisons. Recommendations below.

### Filtering layers with no geometry

```py
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        if not layer.isSpatial():
            # Now we have a layer without geometry
```

### Filtering layers by geometry type

This is the recommended way of filtering by geometry type:

```py
layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry
```

Note: Such comparison includes all polygon variations, like `multi`, `with Z`, `with M`, and others.

### Filtering layers by specific geometry type variations

If you need to test a particular polygon variation, you can use:

```py
layer.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.MultiPolygonZ
```

*Source: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsWkbTypes.html*

Answer (score 5):

To be sure, you can also use the [`wkbType()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsWkbTypes.html) method.

```py
for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.wkbType() == 1:
        print(lyr.name(), "is a point layer")
    elif lyr.wkbType() == 2:
        print(lyr.name(), "is a line layer")
    elif lyr.wkbType() == 3:
        print(lyr.name(), "is a polygon layer")
    elif lyr.wkbType() == 100:
        print(lyr.name(), "is a layer without geometry")
    else:
        print(lyr.name(), "has another type of geometry")
```

The multi-geometries have a distinct number (For example, 5 for a multi-line geometry).

You can get the correspondence of the numbers on the following link:
https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsWkbTypes.html?highlight=geometrytype#qgis.core.QgsWkbTypes.NoGeometry

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have added another link that refers to the class QgsWkbTypes with the correspondance.