# Correction of a script about assigning default styles with PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I have a project with different shapefiles, and I would like to assign different default styles to each of these layers. Thus, when I execute the following code, it only works for the first layer, which is called 'Property Area.' Interestingly, it is not managing to assign the corresponding style, and nothing happens with the other layers. They remain with their original styles without being assigned. Can someone with experience analyze this snippet of my code and tell me what I might be doing wrong?

```
project = QgsProject.instance()

property_area_layer: QgsMapLayer = project.mapLayersByName('Property Area')[0]
if property_area_layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
    property_area_layer.loadNamedStyle('C:/Users/Documents/Vectors/QGIS Styles/Property Area.qml')
    property_area_layer.triggerRepaint()

app_layer: QgsMapLayer = project.mapLayersByName('Permanent Preservation Area')[0]
if app_layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
    app_layer.loadNamedStyle('C:/Users/Documents/Vectors/QGIS Styles/Total APP.qml')
    app_layer.triggerRepaint()

legal_reserve_layer: QgsMapLayer = project.mapLayersByName('Legal Reserve')[0]
if legal_reserve_layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry:
    legal_reserve_layer.loadNamedStyle('C:/Users/Documents/Vectors/QGIS Styles/Legal Reserve.qml')
    legal_reserve_layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Actually, your code worked fine for my two layers of Point and Polygon type. Can you please verify if these files exist `Total APP.qml` and `Legal Reserve.qml` ? What does this `print(vlayer1.loadNamedStyle("D:/qgis_test/vertices.qml"))` return you: `('', True)` or `('Error message', False)` ? Also check the geometry type of each layer, see this thread for more details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377513/filtering-layers-by-geometry-type-using-pyqgis.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the error with two polygon layers. QGIS 3.34.3, Python 3.9.18, Windows 11

Comment: thanks @Taras, the problem was that i needed to close and reopen the program, i think its some cache issue;

Comment: I suggest writing about it as an answer to your own question

Answer (score 0):

I racked my brain trying to understand what could be going wrong, but then I realized that my version of QGIS 3.28.10 was having issues with the cache. Simply restarting the application and running the code again was enough to make it work.